# Compiler complaining of undeclared variable in a macro

Tags: c

I am using a macro defined in the same source file as:

```
#define MY_MACRO (a, b,...) (...)
```

The macro is being used later in the file.

However, the compiler complains:

error: a undeclared (first use in this function).

It's really weird.. am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Please show a minimal example.

Comment: If you want a function macro, the parentheses for the argument list must follow the macro name immediately, without a space. As is, you have defined a simple substitution where `MY_MACRO` is expanded to `(a, b, ...) (...)`, which might not be what you want You can probably run the compiler with a switch ( `-E` in gcc) to show preprocessed output to help you track such problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the problem is that there is a SPACE between `MY_MACRO` and `(a, b, ...)`. It should be like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO(a, b,...) (...)
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove the space between the macro name and the argument list.  The space separates the macro head from the body, so it is being treated as a macro with no arguments that expands into the desired argument list followed by the desired body.